# Understanding prototypes and augmentation in this example

Tags: javascript, prototype, this

The following explanation and code was obtained from the book: **Javascript, the good parts**:

> JavaScript allows the basic types of the language to be augmented. In
>   Chapter 3, we saw that adding a method to Object.prototype makes that
>   method available to all objects. This also works for functions,
>   arrays, strings, numbers, regular expressions, and booleans. For
>   example, by augmenting Function.prototype, we can make a method
>   available to all functions:

```
Function.prototype.method = function (name, func) {
 this.prototype[name] = func;
 return this;
};
```

> By augmenting Function.prototype with a method method, we no longer
>   have to type the name of the prototype property. That bit of ugliness
>   can now be hidden. JavaScript does not have a separate integer type,
>   so it is sometimes necessary to extract just the integer part of a
>   number. The method JavaScript provides to do that is ugly. We can fix
>   it by adding an integer method to Number.prototype. It uses either
>   Math.ceiling or Math.floor, depending on the sign of the number:

```
Number.method('integer', function ( ) {
 return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
});
document.writeln((-10 / 3).integer( )); // -3
```

---

**QUESTION:** Can anyone explain the sequence of events that are taking place in the previous two blocks of code?

**MY CURRENT UNDERSTANDING of the sequence of events:**

The first block of code above seems to be adding a function called `method` to the function prototype `Function.prototype`. The function being added has two parameters (`name`, and `func`). So far so good.

My confusions start to arise on line `this.prototype[name] = func;`. The `this` keyword represents an object. Since I  am assuming that the new function called `method` will be invoked by a function created at some point (like the function `integer()` in the second block of code above), then **I am assuming** that `this` represents the newly created function-object `integer` and any other function that uses it in the future.

I am also assuming that the parameter `name` is the name of the newly created function, and `func` is the actual function that is being created.

Then the line of code `return this;` is returning the object itself.

In the second block of code above, the newly created `method` function is being used to create a function called `integer`. Inside function `integer` exists the following line of code:

```
return Math[this < 0 ? 'ceiling' : 'floor'](this);
```

Why is `this` being compared to `0`? I understand that `Math[...]` will round a number up (if ceiling is inserted) or down (if floor is inserted), though the logic behind `this` being compared to `0`, as well was the code `(this)` lost me completely.

Comment: I guess `'ceiling'` is supposed to be `'ceil'` as in [*Math.ceil*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.ceil)?

Comment: @RobG Well I don't believe anything is wrong with the code since I got that code snippet directly for the book (though you would know better than me for sure). I was more wondering on what the inner parts of the code was doing to get the final result. I made some assumptions in the beginning of my understanding that seemed logical (which could be right or wrong), but towards the end I got completely lost with what `this` was doing

Answer (score 0):

> My confusions start to arise on line `this.prototype[name] = func;`.

The *method* method is supposed to be called on a function object, as in:

```
Number.method(...)
```

so that *this* within the function references the object on which *method* was called. In the above, that's the *Number* constructor and `this.prototype` will reference `Number.prototype`.

> I am also assuming that the parameter name is the name of the newly created function, and func is the actual function that is being created.

Almost. *name* is the name of the property that will be created and *func* is the function that will be assigned to it (strictly, a reference to *func* will be assigned). The following:

```
Number.method('integer', func)
```

adds a property called "integer" to *Number.prototype* and assigns as its value the value (a function reference) provided as the second argument.

> Why is this being compared to 0?

The method is called as method of a number. Primitives can be coerced to objects for the sake of evaluating expressions, so in:

```
(-10 / 3).integer();
```

the result of `-10/3` is a float value (a number primitive, let's say 3.67) on which the method *integer* is called, so within *integer*, *this* represents the number 3.67.

The reason it's compared to zero is so that it's shortened in the right direction, e.g. +3.67 => 3 and -3.67 => -3. The same can be achieved by truncating the number, but [*trunc*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-math.trunc) wasn't available when Crockford wrote his book (though he likely knew it was coming in ECMAScript 2015). He could also have used `|0` but that's perhaps a bit obscure for his purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the sequence of events that is happening

1. `method` function is defined on the `Function` prototype. It should be noted that only objects originating from `Function` would have this property. So, a simple object such as `var a = {key: 'value'}` would not have the `prototype` property
2. `method` function is called on `Number`. It will check if it has function called `method` on its prototypal chain and it will find it since it inherits from `Function`. So, using that a function `integer` is defined on `Number`. So, all the objects inheriting from `Number` will have a function called `integer`.
3. `integer` function is called on number `(-10/3)`. It will again check if `integer` function is present on the prototypal chain for number `(-10/3)` and since we just add a function called `integer` to the `Number` prototype, it will find it and call it.

To answer your specific questions about the value of `this` in each step, in step 1, this is pointing to `Number` because that's where the function is invoked and we will create the passed in function on `Number` prototype using the provided name. In step 2, `this` is pointing to number `(10/3)` because that's what invokes the `integer` function.

The `return this` in step 1 is not really required but it can be used for method chaining

Comparison to `0` is just part of the implementation. The user wants to return the integer part of the number. So, if we call `(-3.4).integer()`, we want to return `-3` which will be given by the `ceiling` function. But if we call `(3.4).integer()`, we want to return `3` which will be given by the `floor`